# In a production environment with nginx and gunicorn, is it better to use a unix socket, or tcp to bind them?

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I can't seem to find anything on the subject online. I found one instance where it is claimed using a unix socket is better because it won't create additional TCP overhead (assuming we're talking about a web server here).

Any idea, anyone?

Comment: Since this question is more about server administration than about programming, it is off topic here.

Comment: "here" being...? :) I presume you meant django. I'll remove the django tag (though in today's world I don't see a distinct separation between programming and production)

Comment: here being [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), perhaps [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) is better suited for this question.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then I most definitely disagree. Being that I'm a developer myself, and based on many other similar questions related to nginx and gunicorn on stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Unix-socket is recommended if you need:

- High throughput on localhost

TCP/IP-socket is recommended if you need:

- Medium+ throughput between networked computers.

TCP adds 30% overhead.